# Por qué no funciona el formulario html para mandar email php?

Tags: php, phpmailer

La verdad es que no tengo mucha experiencia con PHP, pero me doy maña.
No es tan difícil configurar para mandar un email a traves de un formulario html.

Se los digo porque he mirado ya como 10 tutoriales y no me funciona ninguno!
Me estoy frustrando mucho.

---

Les voy a dejar mi index.html
También mi código PHP.
Y ... a ver quien adivina donde esta el error.

### Tengo la página subida a la red y sin embargo no me funciona:
http://fundacionquierovivir.com.ar/correophp/index.html
No entiendo!! es increíble.

mi html:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <form name="frmContacto" method="post" action="sendbymail.php">
        <table width="500px">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="first_name">Nombre: *</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="25">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <label for="last_name">Apellido: *</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="25">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="email">Dirección de E-mail: *</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="35">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="telephone">Número de teléfono:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="25" size="15">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="comments">Comentarios: *</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y mi php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
$email_to = "julian.sosto@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web";

// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['comments'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['first_name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Apellido: " . $_POST['last_name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telephone'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['comments'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he reformulado la pregunta.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator' not found
Podría revisar si la ruta es correcta ?

Comment: como cargás las dependencias en php? usás composer, o algo así? o las bajaste a mano? Tenés mal la referencia a PHPFormValidator. O te falta la dependencia, o te está andando mal el autoload.

La respuesta del php me devuelve esto:
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'FormGuide\PHPFormValidator\FormValidator' not found in /home/c1840509/public_html/correo/src/FormHandler.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /home/c1840509/public_html/correo/handler.php(13): FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler-&gt;__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/c1840509/public_html/correo/src/FormHandler.php</b> on line

Comment: Este formulario es uno de tantos que he buscado intentar hacer funcionar y no puedo. Lo he hecho hasta con formularios más simples. Cualquiera que conozcan que funcione ya me estaría sirviendo de referencia. No entiendo como resolverlo.

Comment: Es así: vos tenés un autoload.php. Ese autoload sirve para no tener que escribir los include.
De otra forma, cada clase que uses la tendrías que incluír a mano: 
include_once("...etc.../miClase.php").
Bueno: por muchas dependencias que te bajes, si tenés mal el autoload, o el autoload no está incluyendo tu carpeta de dependencias, no te va a funcionar. Quizás por eso no te anduvo ninguna.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-html -->

<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitd359baac21f520c04e608f4eed750560::getLoader();

Comment: Perfecto, estás usando composer. Usaste ej composer.json? como incluíste el FormGuide adentro de composer.json?

Comment: Gracias Fede, ahi reviso mejor y te contesto.

Comment: Ahi por ejemplo hice un formulario en html MUCHO más simple y tambien un php más simple. Porque tampoco me funciona?! no entiendo. Modifique la pregunta.

Comment: El error habla de una clase `FormValidator` que no encuentra, pero en tu código no veo nada relativo a esa clase. Quizá tu problema está en que no tienes bien organizados tus archivos o que estás dirigiendo el formulario (en el `action`) al archivo equivocado.

Comment: Es que es un formulario muy básico. Y el PHP también. No veo porque no funcionaría. Voy a intentar algo y vengo.

Comment: LO HE SUBIDO A : http://fundacionquierovivir.com.ar/correophp/index.html
y sigue sin funcionar misteriosamente


me dice que funciona correctamente pero no me llegan los mails ni siquiera en spam

Comment: No se trata de adivinar que es lo que pasa, pero tu servidor que version de php tiene? para que utilizas un name en el form si no utilizas js para mandar el formulario? tu html y php estan al mismo nivel?

Comment: El servidor tiene version PHP 7.3 FPM.
Y no sabria decirte si mi html y mi php estan al mismo nivel. He subido lo que tengo a la pregunta.

Comment: @JuliánFranciscoSosto a lo que se refiere Dohko19 es si ambos archivos están en la misma carpeta (para corroborar si el error puede ser por las referencias). Saludos.

Comment: Si, estan en la misma carpeta.
Les pegaría la imagen para mostarles. Pero si estan en el mismo nivel.

Comment: estan al mismo nivel, miren:
https://ibb.co/zJ2z007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la función incorporada de PHP para enviar correos desde Linux. La misma trabaja "bien" en Windows, pero no de buenas a primeras en sistemas basados en UNIX.
La documentación de PHP dice que se puede utilizar esa función en dichos sistemas, pero [necesitas un MTA](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes) - Mail transfer agent - o sea un MailServer separado, con su respectiva configuración para que lo pueda utilizar.

La solución más fácil de resolver esto es usar otra librería para enviar correo, por ejemplo [PHP mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Con eso garantizas, incluso, que el código sea portable fácilmente de servidores y plataformas. Si no te quieres complicar con eso de la instalación via *composer*, puedes [descargar de los releases](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases). Y una vez descomprimido, dentro del directorio `src/` están los archivos que necesitas.

Una vez ubicados los archivos, configuras un correo siguiendo la documentación. Un ejemplo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'ruta/de/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php'; 
require 'ruta/de/phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    // Activar autenticación SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.tudominio.com';   // SMTP Server
$mail->Username   = 'cuentasmtp@tudominio.com';     // Cuenta SMTP
$mail->Password   = 'el-password';    // Password de la cuenta
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->ClearAllRecipients(); // Elimina direcciones anteriores si se usa iteradamente
$mail->setFrom('cuenta_de_envio@tudominio.com', 'Nombre Del Que Envia');
$mail->addAddress('cuenta_destino@dominio.com');
$mail->addCC('cc_opcional@dominio.com');
$mail->Subject  = 'Titulo del Correo';

$Message = '<html><head>'.PHP_EOL;
$Message .= '</head><body>'. PHP_EOL;
$Message .= '<h3>[ Contenido del correo ]</h3>' . PHP_EOL;
$Message .= '</body></html>'. PHP_EOL;

$mail->Body = $Message;
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Voy a probar esto que me dices y luego les cuento.