# El formulario no funciona para enviar correo PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

No sé que estoy haciendo mal pero el formulario no me quiere hacer el envio, lo tengo alojado en 000webhost pero como les comento no me hace el envio me da el mensaje de error que he creado, qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
<?php

    if ($_POST) {
        $emailTo="miemail@gmail.com";
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
        $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
        $headers='From: '.$_POST['correo'];

        if (mail($emailTo,$nombre,$apellido,$asunto,$headers)) {
            echo '<div class="message-send roboto">Mensaje enviado, revise su correo.</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="message-error roboto">Error, el mensaje no pudo ser enviado.</div>';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

```html
<form class="form" method="POST">

            <p class="roboto form-text">Ingrese su nombre</p>

            <input class="roboto form-input" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Mi nombre es...">

            <p class="roboto form-text">Ingrese su apellido</p>

            <input class="roboto form-input" type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Mi apellido es...">

            <p class="roboto form-text">Ingrese su correo</p>

            <input class="roboto form-input" type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Mi correo es...">

            <p class="roboto form-text">Ingresa tu clave</p>

            <input class="roboto form-input" type="password" name="asunto" placeholder="Mi clave es...">

            <input class="roboto form-send" type="submit">

        </form>
```

Comment: También coloca la función mail() para ver que hace. Saludos.

Comment: te tira algun mensaje de error???... puede q si no te llega el mail tengas q averiguar como configurarlo en 000webhost... osea si funciona la funcion MAIL

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por qué no funciona el formulario html para mandar email php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/365544/80870)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por qué no funciona el formulario html para mandar email php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365519/por-qu%c3%a9-no-funciona-el-formulario-html-para-mandar-email-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás colocando mal los parámetros de la función `mail()`,
fíjate mejor en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

El primer parámetro es el correo de destino, luego el asunto, el mensaje y los headers.
El nombre y el apellido podrias ponerlo en el mensaje o en el header From, pero no van como parámetros directos de `mail()`.