# Función PHP no envía mails a correos gmail

Tags: php, gmail, mail

Trabajo con Hostinger como proveedor de hosting y tengo el script *catálogo.php* que recibe datos de un formulario de una página del mismo sitio en HTML.

**Mi problema: El formulario, que utiliza trabaja con  la función mail() de php, no envía los mails a los correo@gmail.com**

**Nota:** He probado cargar otros emails al formulario y funciona bien con @hotmail.com y @miempresa.com y probé con 2 correos personales @gmail.com y he veríficado que no llegan.

El código es este:

```
    <?php
    $destino    = 'info@lalkasa.com';
    $nombre     = $_POST['fnombre'];
    $empresa    = $_POST['fempresa'];
    $email      = $_POST['femail'];
    $telefono   = $_POST['ftelefono'];
    $msj        = $_POST['fmensaje'];
    $cuerpo = '
    <html bgcolor="#F7F7F7">
    <body>
        <h1><img src="http://nahmastestudio.com/demo/lalka/assets/images/cabecera_mails_catalogo_lalka.png" width="600px"></h1>
        <div>       
    <div>
    <p>'.$nombre.', le hacemos llegar su acceso a nuestro catálogo de productos.</br>
    Muchas gracias.
    </p>
    <p><a href="http://lalka.nahmastestudio.com/public/catalogo_lalka.pdf">Descargar catálogo</a></p>
    </div>
    <TABLE >
    <TR><TH align="left">Nombre</TH>
        <TD>'.$nombre.'</TD>
    <TR><TH align="left">Empresa</TH>
        <TD>'.$empresa.'</TD>
    <TR><TH align="left">Email</TH>
        <TD>'.$email.'</TD>
    <TR><TH align="left">Teléfono</TH>
        <TD>'.$telefono.'</TD>
    <TR heigh="100px"><TH></TH>
        <TD></TD>
    <TR><TH COLSPAN=2 align="left" style="color:#DFDEDE;font-size:13px;"><small>La información contenida en este correo electrónico y sus adjuntos es confidencial. Puede contener información
amparada por el secreto profesional. Si usted no es el destinatario arriba nombrado y ha recibido este correo
electrónico por error, sírvase comunicárnoslo de inmediato vía correo electrónico y eliminarlo de su sistema.
Por favor, tenga presente que cualquier forma de divulgación, copia, distribución o uso de la información aquí
contenida se encuentra estrictamente prohibida.
</small></TH>
        <TD></TD>
    </TABLE>
        
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // Formateo el mensaje a UTF-8 para los campos con tildes
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .="From: Lalka - Distribuidora del Este" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $destino" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    // Ejecuto la funcion para enviar el mail
    mail($email,"Su catálogo de productos Lalka.",$cuerpo,$headers);

    header("Location:../catalogo-enviado.html");
    
?>
```

**¿Alguno entiende porque no llegan los mails a los correos@gmail.com?**

**Solución:** Quitar la mascara de remitente en la cabecera y dejarlo por defecto quitando lo siguiente:

> "From: Lalka - Distribuidora del Este" . "\r\n"

Comment: Revisaste spam en el buzón gmail?

Comment: Si, ya lo probe usando dos emails de gmail y verifique que no llegan.

Comment: Prueba usando [phpmailer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/365544/80870), el cual formatea de forma más precisa y formal el correo. Además de que es cross-platform.

Comment: una pregunta a que se refiere con la mascara del remitente? disculpe mi ignorancia pero soy principiante.

Comment: Me registré en esta web solamente para responderte, nadie de servicio técnico ni de google ni de hostinger, u otros servidores sabían la respuesta y te mandaban a cambiar valores dns desde el Cpanel, toquetear todo y esperá a que haga efecto!.
Muchas gracias por publicar la solución, una colombiana de hostinger me tomaba de boluud0 y daba 800 vueltas y tutos innservibles, la recsm!, GRACIAS CHE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas explicando si utilizas la funcion Mail o PHPMAiler para enviar los correos,

Hostinger tiene sus tutoriales respecto a como debes configurar tu archivo, puedes verlo en:

[Tutoriales Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/send-emails-using-php-mail)

Los errores mas comunes con los que yo me he encontrado son:

1. Gmail tiene que validar que la cuenta te pertenece y tienes que darle acceso a aplicaciones de terceros al correo que se encarga de enviar tus correos.

Cómo revisar el contenido a los que puede acceder un tercero
Puedes revisar el tipo de acceso a la cuenta que tiene un tercero y los servicios de Google a los que tiene acceso.

```
Ve a la sección de seguridad de tu Cuenta de Google.
En "Apps de terceros que pueden acceder a tu cuenta", 
selecciona Administrar el acceso de terceros.
Selecciona la app o servicio que quieres revisar.
```

Revisa: [Google Apps terceros](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=es-419)

2. Mi dominio era nuevo y los MX Records no estaban completamente propagados o mi SPF no estaba configurado.

En tus TXT Records crea uno nuevo;

- HOST: @
- TXT value: v=spf1 include:spf.titan.email include:spf.mx.hostinger.com include:relay.mailchannels.net ~all
- TTL: default value

puedes revisar: [Hostinger SPF Record](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583673-how-to-add-and-remove-spf-records-on-hpanel)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo resolvi.
Gmail me filtraba el mail por utilizar una cabecera donde enmascaraba el nombre del servidor que le enviaba el correo el cliente.
En este caso, como uso la funcion mail() y los mails se envian con el email que dispone mi proveedor de hosting, tuve que enmascarar el nombre de quien enviaba el correo, y hacer eso, considerado phishing es lo que me jugó en contra.

Aqui la solución:

$headers .="From: Lalka - Distribuidora del Este" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $destino" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

Answer (score 0):

**Encontré la falla:**

En esta cabecera esta el drama:

```
$headers .="From: Lalka - Distribuidora del Este" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $destino" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Tuve que quitar la máscara que use para declarar al remitente, porque la función mail() hace uso de un email u369500991@srv153.main-hosting.eu que me brinda mi proveedor de hosting, y para que no le aparezca eso a los usuarios es que defini en la cabecera otra información.

Finalmente, lo suprimi asi:

```
$headers .="From: Lalka - Distribuidora del Este" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $destino" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Quedó todo funcionando.

[image: Resultado de la corrección]