# PHP mail no manda los datos

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, phpmailer

Tengo un proyecto con react y en el archivo donde mando los datos a través de fetch tiene como url un archivo subido a internet esperando para recibir los datos pero parece que los recibe y no los envía o directamente no los recibe(aunque creo que es mas la primera), tal vez esté algo mal en el código de php.

Anyway si me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema se los agradecería muchísimo.

Código de front-end(react)

```
    onSubmit: (values) =>{
                const url = "https://programmark.com/enviar.php"
                const data = {
                    fullname:values.fullname,
                    email:values.email,
                    text:values.text
                }
                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers:{
                        "Content-type": "application/json"
                    }
                }).then(res=> alert("The form has been send!"), console.log(data))
                  .catch(err=> alert("The form could not be send :("))
```

Codigo del script de php

```php
<?php 
    //CUANDO SUBAS TODO AL HOST CORROBORÁ LAS DIRECCIONES URL DE LOS ARCHIVOS(PAGE.JSX[AJAX] Y DEMAS)
    echo "todas putas";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $fullname=htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $mail = $_POST['email'];
            $text = $_POST['text'];
            if(($fullname!==''||$fullname!==null)&&($mail!==''||$mail!==null)){

            //Destinatary
              $to= 'xxx';
              $title='Mail sent from Programmark.com';
              $message=
                "<html>
                    <head>
                        <title>$title</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h4>Fullname: $fullname</h4>
                        <h4>Mail: $mail</h4>
                        <p>Message: $text</p>
                    </body>
                </html>";
                $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                mail($to,$title,$message,$header);
            }
        }
```

Otra cosa, no creo que sea el  `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` porque anteriormente andaba con eso.

Comment: Estas enviando fullname, email y text, mas no submit. El problema deberia estar en el isset, como no lo envias, no pasa la condicion

Comment: Si el hosting es Linux, puedes tener problemas para enviar correos con `mail()`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/365544/80870)