# Enviar mail desde mi pagina

Tags: php, html, mail

Sé que hay muchos foros y muchas respuestas pero hasta ahora ninguna me ha solucionado el problema, tengo un **form** en un `index.php` el cuál al ser llenado debe enviar un mail al presionar el **botón** pero por algún motivo no estaría funcionando y ya no se me ocurren ideas. Este es mi `form`:

```html
<form method="POST" action="enviarMail.php">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Contáctanos</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h4 style="text-align:center">¡Estaríamos felices de poder asesorarte!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row input-container">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="styled-input wide">
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" required />
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="styled-input">
                    <input type="text" id="email" required />
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="styled-input" style="float:right;">
                    <input type="text" id="telefono" required />
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="styled-input wide">
                    <textarea id="mensaje" required></textarea>
                    <label>Mensaje</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input class="btn-lrg submit-btn" id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Este es mi **`enviarMail.php`**:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
if($_POST["mensaje"]) {
    mail("recepcion@frabasoft.com.ar", "Prueba",
    $_POST["insert your message here"]. "From: mail@mail.com");
}
?>
```

Pero una vez que presiono **enviar**, no me llega ningún **mail** y ya no se como hacerlo, ¿Alguien me podría decir?

Comment: Estás enviando desde localhost o desde un dominio?

Comment: Lo estoy enviando desde mi dominio @Bicho

Comment: Si es un host Linux, ¿responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/365544/80870

Comment: definitivamente si es desde tu dominio debes usar protocolo SMTP, abajo adjuntaron una respuesta al problema, puedes marcarla como solución, y el compañero @aeportugal te dejo un link donde hay ejemplo claro del uso de SMTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta fue la solución que hallé:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["comentario"]) ){
$to = "CUENTA_DESTINO@DOMINIO.COM";
$subject = "Mensaje Enviado";
$contenido .= "Nombre: ".$_POST["nombre"]."\n";
$contenido .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n\n";
$contenido .= "Comentario: ".$_POST["comentario"]."\n\n";
$header = "From: CUENTA_DE_TU_DOMINIO@TU_DOMINIO.COM\nReply-To:".$_POST["email"]."\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";
if(mail($to, $subject, $contenido ,$header)){
echo "Mail Enviado.";
}
}
?>
```

Y funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 2):

Es muy posible que tengas alguna limitante en tu proveedor de hosting.

Te recomiendo usar la librería **PHPMailer** qeu es una popular biblioteca de envío de correo para PHP. Es compatible con el envío de correo a través de la función mail() o Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP). Esta biblioteca simplifica el complicado proceso de crear un correo PHP al proporcionar un conjunto de funciones para crear y enviar un correo electrónico.

Configura sus parámetros con una cuenta real existente, muy fácil de hacer y listo! Estarás enviando Emails como si salieran del Outlook (Un decir)!

Éxitos!

Answer (score 0):

podrias tratar de cambiar esto:

```
<input class="btn-lrg submit-btn" id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

por un boton de tipo submit.

Ya probaste si el form llega al archivo .php o si el problema es en el envio del correo

Comment: "Podrías" no es una respuesta. Debes demostrar que funcionan publicando algo que sea ejecutable.